# Sound not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound

Suddenly, sound stopped working. The correct sound entry is set. I tested on windows, and everything is fine .Using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You can run `alsamixer` and check there is various playback channels are muted - there will be `MM` symbol. Press `M` key to unmute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or newer, try this first:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

wait ***ten*** seconds, then run this:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

For further information, access [help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)